# Network Error: Connection Refused in AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssm

I Installed tomcat and AD connectivity configuration also, After that, I am getting 'Network error: Connection refused' while ssh access to the instance.

In Security Groups, all traffic allowed to the bastion host.

I go on through all the solution on StackOverflow,  not working.

also, I Access through System Manager, getting access but it can't switch to root.

```
sh-4.2$ sudo su -
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
sh-4.2$
```

Getting this while accessing to the root from SSM

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved

- Stop the EC2 instance
- Detach the EBS volume from the Instance
- Launch New Ec2 instance
- Attach and Mount the EBS Volume to the Newly launched EC2 instances
- Go to the Attached EBS Volume and Change the permission of the /root, /usr/lib/systemd/system, /var/empty/sshd, /usr/bin/sudo, /etc/sudoers etc.. to Default
- Then Attach the EBS Volume back to the old instance and start it.

it will be fine.